# Module:referencing another module from the desciptor

Tags: maven-2

My assembly descriptor for module (APP1) is:

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
  <assembly>
  <id>report</id>
    <formats>
    <format>jar</format>
  </formats>
  <includeBaseDirectory>false</includeBaseDirectory>
  <moduleSets>
    <moduleSet>
      <includes>
    <include>*-APP2</include>[trying to refer to another module ie module-APP2]
      </includes>
      <sources>
    <fileSets>
      <fileSet>
        <directory>/</directory>
        <includes>
          <include>**/target</include>
        </includes>
      </fileSet>
    </fileSets>
    <excludeSubModuleDirectories>false</excludeSubModuleDirectories>
    <outputDirectoryMapping>/</outputDirectoryMapping>
      </sources>
    </moduleSet>
  </moduleSets>
 </assembly>
```

When I am running the mvn install cmd , I'm getting

```
[WARNING] The following patterns were never triggered in this artifact inclusion filter:
o  '*-APP2'
```

where have I gone wrong?

I modified as :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><assembly>
  <id>report</id>
  <formats>
    <format>jar</format>
  </formats>
  <includeBaseDirectory>false</includeBaseDirectory>
  <moduleSets>
    <moduleSet>
      <includes>
    <include>sampleMaven:module-APP2</include>
      </includes>
      <sources>
    <fileSets>
      <fileSet>
        <directory>/</directory>
        <includes>
          <include>target/*</include>
        </includes>
      </fileSet>
    </fileSets>
    <excludeSubModuleDirectories>false</excludeSubModuleDirectories>
    <outputDirectoryMapping>/</outputDirectoryMapping>
      </sources>
    </moduleSet>
  </moduleSets>
</assembly>
```

still getting :

```
[WARNING] The following patterns were never triggered in this artifact inclusion filter:
o  'sampleMaven:module-APP2'
```

Updated on 18/sep:
Main proj pom.xml-->

http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    4.0.0
    sampleMaven
    anu
    0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
    pom

APP1

```
<module>APP2</module>
```

2)For APP1, the pom.xml is-->

```
   <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
```

anu
    sampleMaven
    0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
  
  4.0.0
  sampleMaven
  APP1
  APP1
  0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
  pom
  
    ../APP2

```
<build>
 <plugins>
    <plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.2-beta-3</version>
    <executions>
    <execution>
      <id>assemblyone</id>
      <phase>compile</phase>
      <goals>
            <goal>single</goal>
      </goals>
      <configuration>
        <finalName>App1</finalName>
        <appendAssemblyId>false</appendAssemblyId>
        <descriptors>
          <descriptor>${basedir}/src/main/resources/assemblies/report.xml</descriptor>
        </descriptors>
      </configuration>
    </execution>
     </executions>
    </plugin>
  </plugins>
</build> 
</project> ...
```

3)Assembly descriptor is -->

report
    
        jar
    
    false

```
 <sources>
  <fileSets>
    <fileSet>
      <directory>/</directory>
      <includes>
       <include>target/*</include>
      </includes>
    </fileSet>
  </fileSets>
  <excludeSubModuleDirectories>false</excludeSubModuleDirectories>
  <outputDirectoryMapping>/</outputDirectoryMapping>
 </sources>
 <binaries>
   <outputDirectory>
      ${module.artifactId}-${module.version}
   </outputDirectory>
   <dependencySets>
      <dependencySet/>
   </dependencySets>
 </binaries>
</moduleSet>
```

On running gettting-->Error stacktrace:

> org.apache.maven.project.DuplicateProjectException: Project 'sampleMaven:APP2' is duplicated in the reactor

Comment: @unknown, I have reformatted your question so it appears correctly. Note that code needs to be indented by 4 spaces (or a tab) to be picked up, you also need a blank line before and after it. Without that indentation it is treated as html, and your xml is not displayed.

Comment: @unknown Hi. If you are satisfied with Rich's answer, maybe you could vote on his answer (the upper arrow), and mark his answer as 'accepted'? Then readers and answerers know in what state your question is, and what to expect. You also get better probabilities that people will take the time to answer your future questions...

Answer (score 3):

Update: The Maven book has a section on [including moduleSets](http://www.sonatype.com/books/maven-book/reference/assemblies-sect-modulesets.html) in assemblies. The approach you have in your example is deprecated. There is also a problem with build order when defining moduleSets from the parent. The parent must be built first so the child can inherit from it, but the child must be built so that the parent can includ it in its assembly.
The following approach addresses that cycle.

Define a parent pom that references an assembly module.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project>
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>name.seller.rich</groupId>
  <artifactId>test-parent</artifactId>
  <packaging>pom</packaging>
  <version>1.0.0</version>
  <modules>
    <module>test-assembly</module>
  </modules>
  <dependencies>
</project>
```

In the assembly module, define a module with a relative path to the actual application module(s), and define the assembly plugin configuration:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>name.seller.rich</groupId>
  <artifactId>test-assembly</artifactId>
  <packaging>pom</packaging>
  <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <modules>
    <module>../my-app2</module>
  </modules>
  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.2-beta-4</version>
    <executions>
      <execution>
        <id>assembly</id>
        <phase>package</phase>
        <goals>
          <goal>single</goal>
        </goals>
        <configuration>
          <finalName>App1</finalName>
          <appendAssemblyId>false</appendAssemblyId>
          <descriptors>
            <descriptor>src/main/assembly/my-assembly.xml</descriptor>
          </descriptors>
        </configuration>
      </execution>
    </executions>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
</project>
```

and my-assembly.xml is defined as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><assembly>
  <id>my-assembly</id>
  <formats>
    <format>jar</format>
  </formats>
  <includeBaseDirectory>false</includeBaseDirectory>
  <moduleSets>  
    <moduleSet>
      <binaries>
        <outputDirectory>
          ${module.artifactId}-${module.version}
        </outputDirectory>
        <dependencySets>
          <dependencySet/>
        </dependencySets>
      </binaries>
    </moduleSet>
  </moduleSets>
</assembly>
```

Building the parent module will then result in a build order of:

1. test-parent
2. my-app2
3. test-assembly

So when the assembly comes to be packaged, my-app2 is built, and is available for inclusion. The binaries declaration will include the jars.

Comment: i tried as per your suggestion.still getting same error.pls chk my edited section in the main question

Comment: +1 I was watching your response, as you didn't entirely solve his problem. I knew you would improve your answer. Glad you did, I'll try to learn about it, as I'm currently having troubles with assembly too...

Comment: @KLE thanks. The Maven book chapter on assembly modules is really pretty good and worth a read. Though neither the book or the assembly plugin docs make it clear that parents can't include children because of the cycle.

Comment: @Richseller..thanks for the valuable inputs.i did as you mentioned.I have put my configuration files in the edited section of my question.I m getting :
[ERROR] 
Duplicated project detected.

Project: sampleMaven:APP2
File: /Users/anu/EclipseWorks3.4/anu/APP2/pom.xml
File: /Users/anu/EclipseWorks3.4/anu/APP2/pom.xml

NOTE: Each project in a Maven build must have a unique combination of groupId and artifactId.

Comment: I think you get this because you've got APP2 declared as a module in both the parent and the assembly. Remove it from the parent so it is included only once

Comment: Bfore I select this module Implementation for my project, i want to know if assembly in mod-1 can inlude the .class files of mod-2/parent project.If so, how should i go about it? i didn't find any satisfactory results while searching google.pls help me out

Comment: A parent project can't have anything but pom packaging, so really shouldn't have any code in it, you should move the code into another module so it can be declared as a dependency by the other modules. You can then use the assembly plugin to copy the jar into your lib directory, or unpack the dependency classes if needed.

Answer (score 2):

I am still looking a solution to build a mutli module application, and I think I am almost there !!! :-)

The trick is to build a seperate module and don't add it to parent because you want to build your parent (which builds all modules) and then invoke the assembly.

I got a zip file that contains all i need, only the executable jar doesn't include sources... but I'll try to figure it out asap. If I can make it work, I'll paste the solution here :)

Peace